# Placeholder BEM

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask if it is possible to do a placeholder but the magnifying glass icon would not be in the place where we are typing the text but on the right outside this area.
HTML code so far:

```html
<body>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="main-nav__logo"></div>
    <div class="main-nav__menu-item-home">ARTYKUŁY</div>
    <div class="main-nav__menu-item-home">O NAS</div>
    <div class="main-nav__menu-item-home">AKTUALNOŚĆI</div>
    <div class="main-nav__menu-item-home">KONTAKT</div>
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="...">
    <button>lupa</button>
  </nav>
</body>
```

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrPSr.png)

Comment: Add your HTML & CSS code here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have questions 2. whether what I wrote is compatible with BEM and whether you can replace the SEARCH button with an icon magnifier

Comment: i add picture :)